# jackson parser exception: unexpected Character

Tags: java, jackson

I am getting a stream of json and trying to dump it into map using jackson. Below is the syntax of json i am getting :

```
M1{"id":"2345","results":"2"}
R1{"Title":"Titanic","country":"US"}
R2{"Title":"Avatar","country":"US"}
```

Now i have below code to parse this stream in jackson parser:

```
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(
                urlConn.getInputStream(),org.apache.commons.lang.CharEncoding.UTF_8);
        Map<String,Object> result = mapper.readValue(stream, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>() { });
```

I am seeing the below eror:

```
Unexpected character ('M' (code 77)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@1d6e3d2; line: 1, column: 2]
```

I want to put each of the two json results into two maps. I cant change the json structure.

can some one explain how can get it to working.

Comment: Your incoming data is not JSON (even though it does contain JSON elements). You are going to have to preprocess the stream.

Answer (score 2):

Is Not JSON:

```
M1{"id":"2345","results":"2"}
R1{"Title":"Titanic","country":"US"}
R2{"Title":"Avatar","country":"US"}
```

Is JSON:

```
[{"key"="M1","id":"2345","results":"2"},
{"key"="R1","Title":"Titanic","country":"US"},
{"key"="R2","Title":"Avatar","country":"US"}]
```

I'm not sure if that exactly matches what your data is supposed to be, but that's how you would represent an array of objects.  If you're going to be using a JSON parser, you need to make sure that what you are parsing is actually JSON.